# Bootstrap a value on two lines

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

With this code I have a menu (I should have 5 entries) in my example I have only 3 menu, and on the right I want to have the email address of the client + log off, my problem is that the email + the log off are on two lines, I want it on one line how it's possible to have it on one line

Thanks

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">General information</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#services">Client</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">Sales</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <text>
                        @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })
                @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
                }
                        </text>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: whats the output of the navbar-right?

Comment: @nozzleman this is what I have : myemail@gmail.com
Log off the code source View `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a class="username" href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">myemail@gmail.com</a><form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input  name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="pKXoA5" /><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></form></li></ul>` the email is one line and the logoff on other line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it... just plug your dynamic code back in there, and you should be good to go:

(bootply: http://www.bootply.com/7K3oQkp7El)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">General</a>
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log Off</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much it works, I have log off a little bit higher than the email, but it's ok for me